# Why are these Rx sequences out of order?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactivex, rx.net

Suppose I write

```
var gen = Observable.Range(1, 3)
  .SelectMany(x => Observable.Range(1, x));
```

The sequence produced is `1 1 2 1 2 3` as expected. But now if I write

```
var gen = Observable.Range(1, 4)
  .SelectMany(x => Observable.Range(1, x));
```

Now the sequence produced is `1 1 2 1 2 1 3 2 3 4` instead of what one would expect `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4`. Why is that? Does `SelectMany()` do some kind of multithreaded merge?

Comment: Maybe you should use a different scheduler: `Observable.Range(1, 4, ImmediateScheduler.Instance).SelectMany(x => Observable.Range(1, x, ImmediateScheduler.Instance))` creates the sequence in order

Comment: `SelectMany` does nothing with scheduling on its own. By default, `.Range` uses the `CurrentThreadScheduler`, which queues actions, but is not multithreaded. In general, across sequences Rx won't be "in order" unless you make them so through operations -- that's exactly why they're observable and not enumerable.

Comment: So is `Observable.Range()` cannot be guaranteed to generate events in order?

Comment: @JeroenMostert No, sequences in Rx will definitely be in order unless you do something to *dis*order them.  The difference between observables and enumerables is push vs pull.  The enumerable grabs data from the source when the client asks, while the observable pushes data to the client when its ready.

Comment: @BrandonKramer: *individual sequences* are in order. As soon as you start to *combine* separate sequences, you need to pay closer attention to what's happening -- while there's an order, it need not be intuitive, or even deterministic (if a threaded scheduler does become involved). That's what I meant.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I see what you mean,  I took what you said too literally.  With that clarification, I agree with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Observable.Range()` itself will always generate its events in order.  However `SelectMany()` doesn't wait for the previous observable to complete before starting the next one.  Which means that as the sequences get longer, there will be more and more overlap, since the next sequence will start before the previous has completed and so on.

If you are trying to get the output to be sequential, then you will need to use a different means of flattening the sequence, such as `Concat()`.

E.g:

```
var gen = Observable.Range(1, 4)
  .Select(x => Observable.Range(1, x)).Concat();
```

Output: 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4

Unlike `SelectMany()`, `Concat()` *does* wait for each sequence to complete before starting the next one.